# Recommender Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, recommendation-engine

I need to put together a Recommender Algorithm for a website. I have come up with a very simple method of achieving this but was wondering if anyone could point me towards any literature or such that could help me get a better idea of how other examples have been put together.

I have been made aware of functionality such as Collaborative filtering, Clustering and Categorization in Apache Mahout but am not to clued up about how the Machine Learning fits into all of this. I can see how to make algorithms for the above (apart from Machine Learning) but was wondering if anyone knew of anything else which could be added to the mix.

Also, what would you say the purpose of a Recommender is, how might it best function? Anyone willing to share a definition?

Thanks!

Comment: You might want to search on "kth nearest neighbour algorithm"

Comment: There seems to be lots on that, I'll have a look, thanks!

Comment: Do you want to tell us more about what problem you are solving? I think a lot can be added to the mix depending on the kind of data you have. Generally speaking, collaborative filtering is very good where you want to suggest based on what others have done. And then there is also content-based filtering. You can make a hybrid algo out of the two of them http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recommender_system#Hybrid_Recommender_Systems

Comment: Here's a [comprehensive book on the topic from 2011](http://www.springer.com/computer/ai/book/978-0-387-85819-7), which you might have access to through a library or something.

Answer (score 5):

There is [an article](https://github.com/gpfvic/IRR/blob/master/A%20Taxonomy%20of%20Recommender%20Agents%20on%20the%20Internet.pdf) which discuses the different possibilities of putting together different algorithms and creating a recommender. The authors have analyzed 37 different systems and their references, and have sorted them into a list of 8 basic dimensions.

Although the paper has been published on 2003 and some of its examples aren't available now, still it can be a very good starting point for researchers to construct their own recommender system.

I'd like to share Robin Burk's definition of recommender systems as in [his paper](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=586352):

> Any system that produces individual recommendations as output, or has the effect of guiding the user in a personalized way to interesting or useful objects in a large space of possible options.

Comment: The linked article is: Montaner M., López, B., de la Rosa, J.Ll. A Taxonomy of Recommender Agents on the Internet. Artificial Intelligence Review 19: 285-330, Junio, 2003.  The link in the answer is dead as of writing this comment, but the article is available at https://github.com/gpfvic/IRR/blob/master/A%20Taxonomy%20of%20Recommender%20Agents%20on%20the%20Internet.pdf

Answer (score 4):

Recommender System is a a topic inside Artificial Intelligence (specifically Data Mining), that aims to suggest new items to users. These items can be of any kind such as books, travels, music, etc.

It is mainly composed of an algorithm that is going to try to extract some knowledge of previous data (like user preferences) to suggests new purchasable items.

It is widely used by Netflix and Amazon. When you see the phrase "Users that bough this also liked that" its highly possible that a recommender system is behind it.

Clustering and other similar algorithms are  approaches used to improve a recommender system. For example, you might want to group users by similarity before applying a specific recommender system, to obtain a better result. For that you could use K-nearest neighbour.

These two articles might help you to understand better the subject:
*Greg Linden, Brent Smith, and Jeremy York. Amazon.com recommendations: Item-to-item
collaborative filtering.*

*Robin Burke. Hybrid recommender systems: Survey and experiments. User Modeling
and User-Adapted Interaction*.

Answer (score 3):

There is now an excellent Coursera course on Recommender Systems, delivered by Joeseph Konstan of U Minn, one of the pioneers in the field. It is free. It is quite good, covering the basic taxonomy of recommender systems including:

```
 - Rating Systems
 - Content Based Filters
 - Collaborative Systems (User-user and Item-item)
 - Dimensionality Reduction (SVD, its meaning, and how to compute it)
 - Hybrid Systems
```

SVD falls squarely into ML, and I found this to be the most coherent and intuitive presentation of it I have seen anywhere - and I have seen a few.

It also shows how to use Lenskit (an academic recommender system toolkit) to create real world systems.
Obviously I liked the course, although I would have liked them to have covered Bayesian methods.